# R shiny filter no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making a Shiny app whose `ui` and `server` functions look like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # App title ----
    titlePanel("All Histograms!"),
    
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(
        
        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId = 'dataset', label = 'Choose a dataset:', 
                        choices = list.files(path = "#path here",
                                             full.names = FALSE,
                                             recursive = FALSE)),
           
            
        ),
        
        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(
            
            # Output: Histogram ----
            plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
            
        )
        
    ))  
server<- function( input, output, session){
    outputdf <- reactive({
        infile <- input$dataset
        if (is.null(infile)){
            return(NULL)
        }
        df<-read_feather(paste0("path_here",infile))
    })
    
    output$checkboxCompany <- renderUI({
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "company_selection", 
                           label="Company", 
                           choices = unique(outputdf()$Company)
        )
        })
    output$checkboxPredictedCondition <- renderUI({
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "predicted_condition_selection", 
                           label="Predicted Condition", 
                           choices = unique(outputdf()$Predicted.Condition)
        )
    })
    
    reactive_data <- reactive({
        df%>% 
            filter(Company %in% input$company_selection)%>%
            filter(Predicted.Condition %in% input$predicted_condition_selection)%>%
            pull(Predicted.Probability)
        
    })
    
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        hist(reactive_data(), xlab = 'Predicted Probability', ylab = 'Frequency')
    })
}
```

The user should be able to select from a list of datasets using `selectInput`, then based on the dataset, two `checkbox` groups `company` and `Predict.Condition` get modified - e.g. one dataset might have options `a,b,c` for `company` while a different dataset has options `a,c,d` for `company`.

Then, depending on the dataset selected and the resulting checkboxes marked, I'm making a reactive histogram.

However, when I run the app, I get "no applicable method for `filter_` applied to an object of class function" error. I'm guessing R thinks that the `df` I'm passing in in `reactive_data` is a function? What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my `reactive_data` should have started with `outputdf()` and my `ui` was missing two `uiOutputs` for `Company` and `Predicted COndition`